# SharePoint 2013/office 365 Test Automation

Tags: testing

I am currently working on SharePoint 2013/Office 365 based intranet portal and we are looking for test automation for our solution.
Basically i want to get answers to following questions:

1. Is Coded UI Test(VS 2012,2013) compatible with Office365/SharePoint 2013. If yes, are there any good articles that can help to learn this scenario?
2. I know we cant do load testing in office 365, but can we somehow script/automate YSlow or PageSpeedChecker as part of ALM/build process? Is there any page weight checker tools available that can be integrated to build process.

Many thanks in advance,
D.